# How to count number of rows, openpyxl

Tags: openpyxl

We have an excel file. For example we have 2 column. A and B. In *A* we have - **5** rows in *B* - **10** rows. When we use function `len(ws['A'])` result is **10** (max of worksheet, not of column A only). Why `len()` works like that? Is it specificity of this function?

Comment: openpyxl keeps track of the bounds of a worksheet and uses these when asked to returns rows of columns. This provides *orthogonality* and makes many functions more reliable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the `len()` you are using is standard Python library `len()`. It simply returns the length of the list you provided `ws['A']`. In your case, for column A I bet that openpxyl is giving you a list that looks like `ws['A'] = ['val1', 'val2', 'val3', 'val4', 'val5', '', '', '', '', '']`. The empty values count as items still.

Comment: You can do `filter(None, ws['A'])`. This removes all items from the list that are empty.

Comment: Is it possible to write direct messages to you @teddy?

Comment: stackoverflow doesn't have any DM capabilities afaik

Comment: StackOverflow has a chat function.

Comment: @BenGoodman: Can you please paste the example code  using the filter process. I tried the similar approach but its not working. Any comments ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58550548/how-to-find-the-active-number-of-elements-on-a-single-column-row-using-openpyxl