# Is there a way with openpyxl to specify column "B" with numbers?

Tags: python, openpyxl, scatter-plot, columnsorting

I am using the scatter chart function and I would like the function to take the length of a specific column using number notation so I can specify the max row length. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how-to-find-the-active-number-of-elements-on-a-single-column-row-using-openpyxl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58550548/how-to-find-the-active-number-of-elements-on-a-single-column-row-using-openpyxl)

Answer (score 0):

Use `get_column_letter`:

```
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter
get_column_letter(1)  # returns "A"
get_column_letter(100)  # returns "CV"
```